# Lockscreen Resolution issue Juno

Tags: release-juno, greeter, resolution

I'm running Juno with dual monitor and Nvidia gtx card. Every time I lock pc it lowers the resolution(I would say 1024x from 1920x) for lock screen but when I login from the boot it showing correct resolution the only problem is with the lock screen.

I know it's not a big deal but it's kind annoying.